# Pytesseract error in using language mode

Tags: python, tesseract, python-tesseract

```
import pytesseract
from PIL import Image

pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = 'C:/Program Files (x86)/Tesseract- 
OCR/tesseract'
result = pytesseract.image_to_string(Image.open('Sanskrit.png'), lang="san")
print(result)


with open('magic.txt', mode='w') as file:
   file.write(result)
   print('see > the output file')
```

This is the above code that I tried to execute. This code works well when I am using lan="eng" but doesn't seem to work for any other languages. I have already download the tessdata files for all the languages and I am using Tesseract-OCR 4.00dev version of the engine.

Any help regarding this would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: What if you try from the command line `tesseract img out -l san`? What is the stacktrace?

Comment: Okay so i tried running the above command and it shows a pop up that tesseract.exe has stopped working. I already reinstalled the Tesseract-OCR engine.

Comment: Without more informations all I can say is that it seems that your installation of tesseract does not seem to work correctly. Perhaps you might want to try a stable version instead of the dev version as a starting point

Comment: @Adonis Well I tried it with a stable version and its working.. Thanks for your help.